# Trying to add a conditional to a function, and receiving an error on execution

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, whitelist

So, first and foremost, it's important to note that I'm adding a feature to something I didn't design. I'm really new to JavaScript, and I'm trying to edit an existing Discord bot. I discovered that the simplest way to achieve my goal would be to edit the root function at which it generates Random numbers. The relavant snippet of the original code (taken from the dice-expression-evaluator module https://github.com/dbkang/dice-expression-evaluator) is as follows:

```
Dice.prototype.roll = function () {
     var rolls = [];
     var sum = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < this.diceCount; i++) {
          var roll = random.integer(1, this.sideCount) * this.coefficient;
          rolls.push(roll);
          sum += roll;
     }
     return {roll: sum, dice: rolls};
};
```

This original code works just fine, but doesn't include my desired feature (a simple-but-verbose sort of whitelist.) the 4 variables not defined in that particular code block are rather self-explanatory. My version of the code (slightly edited for privacy reasons) is as follows:

```
Dice.prototype.roll = function () {
  var rolls = [];
  var sum = 0;
  var range = this.whitelist(); //already tried it with () after whitelist
  console.log(range.join(','));
  for (var i = 0; i < this.diceCount; i++) {
    var roll = random.integer(range[0], range[1]) * this.coefficient; //changed the 2 function arguments, but both are still integers
    rolls.push(roll);
    sum += roll;
  }
  return {roll: sum, dice: rolls};
};

Dice.prototype.whitelist = function () {
  let user0 = "a";
  let user1 = "b";
  let user2 = "c";
  let user3 = "d";

  let user = message.author.id;
  let die = this.sideCount;
  console.log(user);
  console.log(string(die));
  if (user==user0) {
    var min = Math.ceil(0.76 * die);
    var max = die;
  } else if (user==user1) {
    var min = Math.ceil(0.76 * die);
    var max = die;
  } else if (user==user2) {
    var min = 1;
    var max = die;
  } else if (user==user3) {
    var min = 1;
    var max = die;
  } else {
    var min = 1;
    var max = die;
  }
  return [min, max];
};
```

The message.author.id variable is available to the function that started the whole function chain 3 scopes up, but in MY version of the code, (even after correcting a few missing semicolons and similarly minute errors) a dice expression that is perfectly functional in the original code generates an "invalid dice expression" error. Other than the introduction of a new variable and the variables in the random.integer call, I see no functional difference between the old and new versions of Dice.prototype.roll. By my understanding, my whitelist function returns an array of integers, and those integers are being injected directly into the random.integer function call in a perfectly reasonable way... I am incredibly confused.

Comment: Try `var range = this.whitelist();` and add a `console.log(range.join(','))` right after it for making sure you get what you expect.

Comment: After following your advice, console.log returned '1,' which means that (since I'm user0 and this.sideCount = 20 when testing) the desired output should be '16,20' right now. also noticed that I missed a few semicolons and forgot to put any variable declarations, corrected, added console.log for user and die within whitelist, tested with "range = this.whitelist()" and "range = Dice.prototype.whitelist" (dice isn't calling whitelist, a separate file in the same module is.) and now I'm not even getting console logging anymore. I'm now even more confused. :/

Comment: As you had to change a lot of things, please update your question with the latest. Please use `this.whitelist()`, it makes no sense to do `Dice.prototype.whitelist`. Use proper debugging to step through your code and check where it goes different from what you expect.

Comment: I've edited with all my changes, as you requested, but, like I said, I'm really new at this, so I don't even know what you mean by "proper" debugging

Comment: Maybe you can create a fiddle that reproduces the issue, because I can't: https://jsfiddle.net/rsrb0xoh/

Comment: a) that website is brilliant, and I wish I'd found it sooner. b) I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on the site, c) I'm not sure why, but I just don't think the whitelist function has access to the variables it needs to perform its job. I tried to pass the user id to the whitelist function by passing it as an argument (with what I believe to be appropriate handling) in every relavant function call between whitelist and the top-level bot command handling script that ALREADY uses it successfully, with no success... and for some reason, the console logs still aren't showing up anymore.